# CSS Property for Cursor to auto move

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a multiline text box with around 25-30 lines. When I scroll it, the cursor remains at the same position. It creates problem when I am using the app on a Android mobile device. In the below case when I scroll up, I can go till 1 but cursor remains at 25 only. In mobile device because of this It does not allow me to scroll. It takes me to 1 but then comes back to the position where the cursor is. i.e 25

[image: Scenario is :]

Is there any CSS property that I can set to this html Text Area and can have the cursor move along as I scroll.

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS only affects styling of the elements in the DOM. What you are looking for requires cursor detection (a cursor means interaction, which is the realm of JavaScript).

Perhaps you can solve your mobile issue by scrolling up, and while holding down your finger on the scroll bar, use another finger/hand to press next to 1 to move the cursor there. Then you can let go of the scroll bar.